# How to set external display (Viewsonic TD 1655) to vertical mode?

Tags: display

I have an external monitor (ViewSonic TD 1655) connected to my Macbook Pro (macOs 12.2) through USB Type-C port. I want to set the display to vertical mode. Is this possible? I checked device's own manual but there was no information about that.

Comment: It quite literally states and provides an image on the [product landing page](https://www.viewsonic.com/global/products/lcd/TD1655#specs) that it supports vertical layout.  Have you [rotated your display image in Settings](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh11534/mac)?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Setting the display to vertical mode is a native feature of the MacOs. It doesn't have anything to do with the external display's own settings. To do it:

System Preferences > Displays > (select display) > Display Settings

Set `Rotation` to 90 degrees.

[image]